# MiKTeX can not update

Tags: errors, miktex, windows, update

I'm trying to install MiKTeX on a windows 10 machine. While updating after installation it stuck on package miktex-zzdb1-2.9 and says

```
package="l3backend", arhiveFile="C:\Users\portable\AppData\Local\Temp\mik239.tmp", expectedMD5="47f7d88feead7c8108a86ad8ec5d0422", actualMD5="c42606db1554c2f3248bdd436447cdd6"
```

Comment: try another repository, it it errors too wait a day, and then make a bug report on the miktex github.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: it seems there was an update yesterday (not visible on miktex.org, but on the site I usually download from, which is `distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr`, and while most updated files date from the 8th of may, the `miktex-zzdbi-2.9.tar.lzma` files date from the 7th.